# What are loyalty cards?

Tags: xbox-fitness

Two closely related subquestions.

How do you acquire them other than as an reward from completing time-limited challenges? What can you do with them once you acquire them?

Answer (score 1):

Punchcards are related to the Xbox Live [Rewards Program](http://rewards.xbox.com/myrewards/) that change monthly. January's challenge was related to Xbox Fitness. So you won't see it there now, but you can see this month's (Feb) Challenges.

You need to sign up and activate your Live Account to begin receiving rewards, so unless you were previously activated you might not receive your punches for fitness.